automatic requirements.txt in pycharm do not generate
I have faced a strange issue with automatic requirement.txt in pycharm.
When I run pip freeze > requirements.txt as always, it adds multiple packages from my virtual environment (some of them I do not use). I need to add only modules that are currently in all imports in my python project (Python 3.12.2)
So, when I run command Add imported packages to requirements I see loading screen and after that my requirements file is still empty.
gif from my pycharm
I tried different options in Add imported packages to requirements command. I tried pip freeze from global environment (It adds all packages from global python interpreter). I tried .\venv\Scripts\pip.exe freeze (It adds some of useless modules). I guess, I can manually add imported modules with versions from pip list, but I think this way pip install requirements.txt in the future will work incorrectly.
What can I do to make automatic pycharm command work to generate requirements.txt correctly?
My assumption: this bug is somehow connected with virtual environment.
